# ReferenceError: answer is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.button.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, referenceerror

I am new to the programming world and have been working on a trivia-game style project. The problem I am encountering is as follows: "Uncaught ReferenceError: answer is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.button.onclick". 
My question is as follows: How are my question answers not being stored when pressing an answer and what is a better way to define answer in my code? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Trivia Game</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="trivia">
            <h1>A Golfer's Trivia</h1>
            <!-- for question -->
            <div id="questionName">
                <p id="question"></p>
            </div>

            <p id="progress"></p>
            <!-- options for the questions -->
            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="btn0"><span id="option0"></span></button>
                <button id="btn1"><span id="option1"></span></button>
                <button id="btn2"><span id="option2"></span></button>
                <button id="btn3"><span id="option3"></span></button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p id="timer"></p>
                <p id="show-clock"></p>
            </div>


            </div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/game.js"></script>

</body>

    </html>``
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
// Keeping score

var unanswered = 0;
var questionIndex = 0;
var score = 0;
var questions = 0;
var answer;


function Quiz(questions) {
    this.score = 0;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.questionIndex = 0;
}
function getQuestionIndex() {
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

function endGame() {
    return this.questions.length === this.questionIndex;
}

function guess(answer) {

    if (this.getQuestionIndex() === correctAnswer(answer)) {
        this.score++;
    }
    this.questionIndex++;
}

// functions for questions

function Question(text, choices, answer) {
    this.text = text;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
}

// check user answer
function correctAnswer(choice) {
    return choice === this.answer;
}

// have questions appear if game is still going
function populate() {

    console.log("populating");
    if (endGame()) {
        showScores();
    }
    else {
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = getQuestionIndex().text;

        // have options appear for each question
        var choices = getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("option" + i);
            element.innerHTML = choices[i];
            guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
        }
        showProgress()
    }
}

// store user guess
function guess(id) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function () {

        questionIndex++;
        populate();
        guess(answer);

    }
}
// show which question player is on
function showProgress() {
    var currentQuestionNumber = questionIndex + 1;
    var element = document.getElementById("progress");
    element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + questions.length;
}

// display scores at end of game
function showScores() {
    var gameOver = "<h1>Results</h1>" + "<h2 class='corr score'> Correct Answers: " + score + "<h2>" + "<br>" + "<h2 class = 'wrong score'>Wrong Answers: " + (questions.length - score) + "<h2 class = 'unanswered score'>Unanswered: " + "<h2>";
    var results = document.getElementById("trivia");
    results.innerHTML = gameOver;


}

// sets of questions, options, answers
var questions = [
    new Question("Where was the game of golf originally founded?",
        ["Scotland", "China", "England", "United States"],
        "Scotland"),
    new Question("Who is the only female golfer to make a cut at a PGA Tour event?",
        ["Michelle Wie", "Annika Sorensteim", "Lexi Thompson", "Babe Zaharias"],
        "Babe Zaharias"),
    new Question("What is the name for a hole-in-one on a par five?",
        ["Triple Eagle", "Double Ace", "Condor", "Albatross"],
        "Condor"),
    new Question("Who holds the record for the most PGA Tour victories?",
        ["Tiger Woods", "Jack Nicklaus", "Ben Hogan", "Sam Snead"],
        "Sam Snead"),
    new Question("What percentage of golfers will never achieve a handicap of 18 or less?",
        ["50 percent", "73 percent", "80 percent", "91 percent"],
        "80 percent"),
    new Question("How many dimples are on a standard regulation golf ball?",
        ["336", "402", "196", "468"],
        "336"),
    new Question("Who was considered the first professional golfer in history?",
        ["Bobby Jones", "Byron Nelson", "Walter Hagen", "Old Tom Morris"],
        "Walter Hagen"),
    new Question("Who is the youngest player to win the Masters?",
        ["Tiger Woods", "Jack Nicklaus", "Jordan Speith", "Arnold Palmer"],
        "Tiger Woods")
];


populate();


var intervalId;


$("#btn").on("click", run);

//  The run function sets an interval

function run() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);


}

var timeLeft = 10;
var displayClock = document.getElementById('timer');

var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft === 0) {


        unanswered++;
        questionIndex++;
        populate();

        alert("You did not answer in time!");
        timeLeft = 10;

        // reset timer, pull question
        run();
    } else {
        displayClock.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds remaining';
        timeLeft--;
    }
}

run();
```

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: I think your guess function needs another parameter. `function guess(id, answer){...}`

Comment: Your Quiz object doesn't seem to encompass all the things you'd like it to, judging by your use of "this". After you post the html we can test it and help you fix. You shouldn't have a global "questions" and a "this.questions", etc.

Comment: Also, to add methods to a "class", you need to use the prototype. So like `Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex=function(){...}`

Comment: To add to @sbrass first comment, it's also not entirely clear to me that you want to call `guess` recursively -- and you're also declaring two `function guess()`es

Comment: I just posted the HTML, thank you all for the quick replies. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're facing another problem here. Here are 2 functions taken off your script:

`guess(any)` version 1

```
function guess(answer) {
    if (this.getQuestionIndex() === correctAnswer(answer)) {
        this.score++;
    }
    this.questionIndex++;
}
```

`guess(any)`version 2

```
function guess(id) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function () {

        questionIndex++;
        populate();
        guess(answer);

    }
}
```

You have 2 of a function named `guess()`. Although the names of both values vary, from Javascript's standpoint they both look like this:

```
function guess(value){}
```

How is JS supposed to know which of them you intend to call?

Rename at least one of them in order to having total unambiguousness among your function names. And try again.

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem or answered your question.